# "Gray code" of all permutations

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory, hamiltonian-graphs, hamiltonian-paths

Informally asking, can we step through all permutations of the set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ by just using transpositions?

More formally: For any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ let $[n] = \{1,\ldots,n\}$ and let $S_n$ be the set of all bijections (permutations) $\pi:[n]\to [n]$. For any set $X$ let  $[X]^2 = \big\{\{x,y\}: x\neq y\in X\big\}$. We let $\pi,\psi\in S_n$ be connected by an edge if "they are one transposition away from each other", or more formally, set $$E_n = \big\{\{\pi,\psi\}\in [S_n]^2:\exists a<b\in[n]:\psi = (a\;\;b)\circ\pi\big\}.$$

For what $n\in\mathbb{N}$ does the graph $(S_n, E_n)$ allow for a Hamiltonian cycle? Or at least for a Hamiltonian path?

Comment: I think maybe this has been answered here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/91734/are-there-hamilton-paths-in-cayley-graphs-of-coxeter-groups

Comment: [Relevant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Trotter_algorithm)

Comment: It is up to you of course but I would add the [tag:reference-request] tag: this kind of thing looks of such huge demand in various practical problems that it must be either widely known or impossible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [V. L. Kompel'makher and V. A. Liskovets, "Sequential generation of arrangements by means of a basis of transpositions", *Kibernetika* **3**, 17, May-June, 1975](http://www.coga.tu-berlin.de/fileadmin/i26/coga/kompelmakherLiskovets.pdf):

> It is well known ([1], p. 28) that all $n!$ arrangements of $n$ symbols can be ordered without repetition so that each can be obtained from the previous one by a single transposition.

See also [C. Savage, "A survey of combinatorial Gray codes", *SIAM Rev.*, **39**, 605 (1997)](https://doi.org/10.1137/S0036144595295272):

> Examples of combinatorial Gray codes include (1) listing all permutations of $1  \dots n$ so that consecutive permutations differ only by the swap of one pair of adjacent elements
>   [Joh63, Tro62]

This is also addressed in Example 7.3.1 in Joyner's [*Adventures in Group Theory*](https://books.google.com/books?id=iM0fco-_Ri8C).

Answer (score 5):

In Knuth's [second fascicle of volume 4 of *The Art of Computer Programming*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201853930), he gives "algorithm P" (or more colloquially, the *method of plain changes*) for generating the permutations of a sequence with *distinct* elements by repeatedly interchanging adjacent pairs.

[image: algorithm P]

---

Earlier in the book, however, Knuth gives a cold shower on the possibility of doing something similar for multisets with repeated elements. He gives the following example, which does not have a Hamiltonian path:

[image: Knuth's multiset example]

Comment: Knuth is using a very restricted set of transpositions, only those of the form $(i\ j)$ with $j=i+1$; this shows that in fact one can do even better than OP is looking for in the permutation case, but it also means that there may still be a Hamiltonian path of OP's form even through multisets (for instance, $2112$ and $2211$ would be adjacent in OP's graph but not in the given one.)

Comment: "plain changes" must be a reference to the art of English change ringing.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_ringing

Comment: @Noam, yes, the bell ringing at Cambridge is mentioned on that page of Knuth's fascicle, among other things.